# jQuery: On submit is invoked before on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have this piece of code:

```
var valueClicked;

$("#frmEditDocument :submit").on('click', function (e) {
    valueClicked = e.target.value;
});

$('#frmEditDocument').on('submit', function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        if (valueClicked == undefined) {
            alert("ValueClicked is undefined");
            return false;
        }
        $("#buttonId").val(valueClicked);
        $(this).find(':submit').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
});
```

Everything is working **almost always** as expected (after submit the form the buttons are grayed out). But only on Chrome on some random occasions the `valueClicked` variable is undefined, because *on submit* is invoked before *on click*. Do you have any ideas what is wrong with this code? Or maybe the problem is with Chrome itself? How can I correct this code to work properly on Chrome too?

Comment: question: is this just a theoretical test? The obvious solution to the problem would be just to handle one of the events, not both.

Comment: @Satpal I thought the same, but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/jjz2x3cd/. May be worth adding as a feature request

Comment: I can't replicate this https://jsfiddle.net/n4cwezng/? The question title anyway

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Agree with _worth adding as a feature request_

Comment: @ADyson Unfortunately there is no reliable and universal way to find the button that caused the form submission, so I need to handle the onclick event.

Comment: @romanoza in that case then maybe don't handle the submit event? Have a click event that handles all the possible submit buttons (which it looks like you've got already), and then call the submit method of the parent form manually, once you've done all the rest of your necessary processing.

Comment: Circling back to this, if one of the answers below helped you solve the issue, you should click to accept the answer. If not, you could provide a comment on what is still causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me aswell.

The only solution is to use setTimeOut. You can use a setTimeOut on submit to let click event execute before submit.

Just don't give a very high value for timer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to avoid this sort of race condition between two events.

When it cannot be avoided, you can hack it by putting a delay on the code that you need to execute last, like this:

```
<script>
var valueClicked;

$("#frmEditDocument :submit").on('click', function (e) {
    valueClicked = e.target.value;
});

$('#frmEditDocument').on('submit', function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
    console.log( valueClicked) ;
   }, 100);
return false;
});

</script>
```